How to use GeoTools GML types in pidf-lo generated classes
Using shape classes generated from opengis https://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/profiles/geoshape/0.1.0/ results in classes using this generated values, i.e:
public class PrismType extends AbstractSolidType {
@XmlElement(
    required = true
)
protected SurfacePropertyType base;

However, it is needed for the project that some types as SurfacePropertyType, should be referenced directly frome GeoTools library, for further conversions. For example, this Prism base will be used to generate a Polygon
using GeoTools. Is there a way that I can directly import these parameters (i.e SurfacePropertyType) from GeoTools library, instead of using the ones that are being created from .xsd files? The idea is that these classes remain in the build directory and are generated in compile time to reduce the complexity of the project.

I think the only way to make this work without resorting to Adapter classes is to build your new objects using the GeoTools codegen module, see the manual for a description of the process.
If these new bindings are (becoming) an OGC standard then please consider contributing the work to GeoTools so that they are useful to the whole community and get kept up to date as the library upgrades.

Thanks for the response. I'll try to generate using codegen and share the results.
